# how can i tell if screen 4.0.3 is multi-threaded?

Tags: gnu-screen

I got screen 4.0.3 running on my redhat 5.9 VM. I am trying to figure out ways to optimize the VM performance.

I read that for single threaded applications, it is better to not give the VM too many vCPUs because it leads to more performance overhead. But how do I know if screen is a multithreaded application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter if `screen` itself is multithreaded. The work it does is really lightweight and you would likely need quite a lot of `screen` windows to create a noticeable impact.

However, every `screen` window will create at least one new process (not a thread) to run the program it displays. These processes might or might not be multithreaded (dependent on what you run), but they will never be threads of the screen process.

Comment: actually I might have enough users who launch enough sessions of screen to start making a difference. I know at least one group of 200 or so  people who really like their screens. and this server serves several groups.